# Sequence of partial sums converge

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be a Banach space and a sequence $(x_n) \subseteq X$ be such that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|x_n\|$ converges in $\mathbb R$. Prove that the sequence $S_n=x_1+...+x_n$ converges in $(X,\|.\|)$.

This seems very obvious but I can't explain. It is said $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|x_m\|$ converges so that means every term in the $S_n$ converges so the sum of these convergence limits add up to a finite number so $S_n$ converges.
This is what I think.

But I don't know how to actually answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : try to prove that $S_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. As $(X, \| \cdot \|)$ is a Banach space, you will be able to conclude that $S_n$ converges in $X$.

> Let $\epsilon >0$. We want to find $N>0$ such that for all $n>m>N$, $\|S_n-S_m\|<\epsilon$. But $\|S_n-S_m\| = \|x_{m+1}+\cdots + x_n\|$... so you can use the triangle inequality, and your hypothesis, which says that there is an integer $N'>0$ such that $\sum_{n≥N'} \|x_n\|<\epsilon$.

More hints:

> You can take $N'=N$. Indeed, if $n>m>N$ then $$\|S_n-S_m\| = \|x_{m+1}+\cdots + x_n\| \leq \sum_{k=m+1}^n \|x_k\| \leq \sum_{k≥m+1} \|x_k\| \leq \sum_{k≥N} \|x_k\| < \epsilon$$

NB : your have proved that the [absolute convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence) implies the convergence, in every Banach space. Actually, it is possible to show that if a normed space satisfies the property "absolute convergence $\implies$ convergence" , then it is a Banach space!

---

To answer your comment more precisely:

This is because $A_K = \sum_{n=1}^{K}\|x_n\|$ converges to $L =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|x_n\|$ when $K \to \infty$.
Then, there exists $N'=K>0$ such that

$$|A_{k-1}-L|=\left|\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\|x_n\| \right|<\epsilon$$ 
for all $k≥N'=K$. In particular this holds for $k=N'$, so that

$$\left|\sum_{n=N'}^{\infty}\|x_n\| \right|<\epsilon$$
as desired.

Comment: When you say "there is an integer $N'>0$ such that $\sum_{n≥N'} \|x_n\|<\epsilon$", so this is basically because of the fact that there exists $K \in \mathbb N$ such that for $n>K$, we have $|x_n|<1$ right? So after a certain point, the sum of terms after n>K would be less than epsilon. Is this where you arrive to the quotes?

Comment: This is because $A_M = \sum_{m=1}^{M}\|x_m\|$ converges to $L =\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\|x_m\|$ when $M \to \infty$. Then, there exists $N'>0$ such that $$|A_{n-1}-L|=\left|\sum_{m=n}^{\infty}\|x_m\| \right|<\epsilon$$ for all $n≥N'$. In particular this holds for $n=N'$

Comment: are the m's meant to be n's?

Comment: Yes, I should have written $n$'s. Do you understand my previous comment or is it too confusing?

Comment: in the question I originally wrote by mistake $\sum _ {n=1}^{\infty} |x_m|$ but it should have been $x_n$.

Comment: its really confusing, its probably my fault for writing my q wrong...

Comment: @snowman : I edited my answer.

Comment: in your edit, since we know $$\left|\sum_{n=N'}^{\infty}\|x_n\| \right|<\epsilon
$$ does that mean $$ \sum_{n=N'}^{\infty}\|x_n\| <\epsilon$$??? Because in the more hints part, you didn't have any modulus signs.

Comment: @snowman : yes, these two quantities are equal, since $\|x_n\|$ is positive, and $|y|=y$ if $y≥0$ (take $y$ to be the sum of the $\|x_n\|,n≥N'$).